# Error:SQL Problems: ERROR :operator does not exists:date>= character varying

Tags: postgresql, ireport

i am using iReport 3.6.0 with postgresql database ,for date type parameter its giving the following error when writing query **"Error:SQL Problems: ERROR :operator does not exists:date>= character varying"** please help

Answer (score 1):

There should be datefield >= textfield::date.
I think that there would be comparing two date fields not two textfields so the datefield::text >= textfield would be rather wrong.

Answer (score 0):

See [PostgreSQL 8.3 Release Notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/release-8-3.html#AEN86615) for explanation and workaround. You should use

```
datefield::text>=textfield
```

Answer (score 0):

The cast function help too:

```
cast(date_trunc('year', current_date) as text)
```